# Erlang and SQL Injection Attacks

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, erlang

I work with the Oracle and MySQL Databases on a daily basis, from erlang application middle-ware. In these middle-ware applications, i am running `Nitrogen Web Framework` and `Yaws Web Server` plus a couple of erlang applications like `RabbitMQ`. The applications run within a trusted intranet despite their being vulnerable to `SQL injection`. 
 Attacks such as documented here: http://sqlzoo.net/hack/ are very able to render these applications useless. Is there a library (Erlang) or techniques of how i can prevent these attacks ? I have known that in other languages like `PHP`, ensuring that all parameters are `stringified` by escaping any `single-quotes` that may be inserted by a user or attacker.
Speaking of `escaping all single-quotes` in a string parameter, i came up with a `replace_all` function but it doesnot seem to solve my needs, because i thought i would find a way of replacing all `single-quotes (')` with an `escaped version of themselves (\')`.

```
replace(Char,With,String)-> replace(Char,With,String,[]).

replace(_,_,[],Done)-> lists:reverse(Done);
replace(Char,With,[Char|Rest],Buffer)->
    replace(Char,With,Rest,[With|Buffer]);
replace(Char,With,[Any|Rest],Buffer)->
    replace(Char,With,Rest,[Any|Buffer]).
```

Testing it on a few examples:

```
3> sql_protect:replace($m,$k,"muzaaya").
"kuzaaya"
4> sql_protect:replace($a,$u,"muzaaya").
"muzuuyu"
5>
```

But how do i use this function to escape all single quotes. To have say `String = "' OR 1=1'"`, changed to: `String = "\' OR 1=1\'"`.
 Your help is much appreciated.
**EDIT**

---

What do you think about this:  if i have a list of all `ORACLE SQL KEYWORDS` and `SQL SERVER KEYWORDS` and `MYSQL KEYWORDS` in one list and for each query parameter, i split it into words ( that is if it contains spaces), and then i check to ensure that none of these contained words is a reserved word, i would prevent many sql injection attacks.
 There seems to be a better way.

Comment: Erlang can't do prepared statements? o.0

Comment: Yes, don't write your own escaping function -- use SQL query parameters instead.  With parameters, you don't interpolate untrusted input into your SQL, so you don't have to worry about escaping anything.  I don't know Erlang, but a quick Google search for "erlang sql parameters" finds many references.

Comment: i am sort of using `ODBC` to commmunicate with the Databases. I have not found ways of using `prepared statements` via `ODBC`. Atleast for Mysql this may be possible. But the only way i am communicating with oracle is by sending SQL statements through ODBC Connections. Thank you Guys

Comment: If you're using the Erlang odbc library, the function you are looking for is [param_query](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/odbc/getting_started.html#param_query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape not only `'` but special symbols like `\`, `\0` and so on too. So the quote function would look like (took it from our mysql driver):

```
quote(String) when is_list(String) ->
    [39 | lists:reverse([39 | quote(String, [])])]; %% 39 is $'
quote(Bin) when is_binary(Bin) ->
    list_to_binary(quote(binary_to_list(Bin))).

quote([], Acc) ->
    Acc;
quote([0 | Rest], Acc) ->
    quote(Rest, [$0, $\\ | Acc]);
quote([10 | Rest], Acc) ->
    quote(Rest, [$n, $\\ | Acc]);
quote([13 | Rest], Acc) ->
    quote(Rest, [$r, $\\ | Acc]);
quote([$\\ | Rest], Acc) ->
    quote(Rest, [$\\ , $\\ | Acc]);
quote([39 | Rest], Acc) ->        %% 39 is $'
    quote(Rest, [39, $\\ | Acc]); %% 39 is $'
quote([34 | Rest], Acc) ->        %% 34 is $"
    quote(Rest, [34, $\\ | Acc]); %% 34 is $"
quote([26 | Rest], Acc) ->
    quote(Rest, [$Z, $\\ | Acc]);
quote([C | Rest], Acc) ->
    quote(Rest, [C | Acc]).
```

Comment: may i combine this with a check whether the supplied parameters contain `SQL` reserved words that an attacker could have injected, or this function is sufficient enough to ensure that even if the reserved word is injected, the Database will treat as a value, Not as part of SQL statement ?

Comment: You should use this function to encode any string parameter you want to insert into your query. As you can see, it adds quotes around the parameter so all the contents inside will be parsed as a string. So you don't have to worry about keywords.

Comment: i also found that to escape oracle single quotes you need another single quote, so they become two.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the erlang libraries, but I would assume that you could create [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) which when executed automatically 'sanitizes' your strings. This is even the preferred method in the php-land, with PDO and mysqli. The escape_strings and mysql driver are AFAIK deprecated.

Comment: erlang is **not** a dialect of php

Comment: Never said it was. The original poster referenced php, so I referenced php back